# Trying to Find a Windows "XP Comment" Editor

Tags: windows, exif

The "Comments" Field that can be displayed in Windows Explorer is sometimes referred to as the "XP Comment", as opposed to EXIF and other Metadata Comment fields

The whole subject seems to me to be shrouded in mystery that borders on voodoo

[ExifTool by Phil Harvey](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/#tagnames) looks like a good tool for editing Metadata, but I'm interested in editing the Comment shown in Windows Explorer itself

I'd be grateful to anyone who can point me to

1) a Windows Spec for this field        and/or
2) an App, SDK or some Code to edit it **for any file type**

Comment: I'm going to venture a guess that this is the [System.Comment property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I use the `exiftool` created by Phil Harvey. The command to modify your XP Comment looks like

```
exiftool -XPComment="new comment" image.jpg

exiftool -XPKeywords="new tag" image.jpg
```

Now you can directly modify the metadata seen in the windows property file manager. This mean when you right click on `your image > properties > details` you will see the comment and tag shown above!

http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/install.html

Answer (score 0):

At least on Windows 8 you can edit this field directly in the Details pane of the Explorer.

1. Locate File in Explorer
2. Make sure "Home > Details-Pane" is selected
3. Modify the value in the field "comments:" in the Details pane on the right hand side.